# YES/NO - is there a way to improve mouse dragging with pure SVG tools?

Tags: svg, mouse, drag

So I was spending some time playing around with pure (no external libraries) SVG elements dragging.

In general all works, but there is this nasty issue for fast moving mouse:
- when user mousedowns a draggable SVG element close to its edge
- then drags (mousemove) such draggable too fast
- the mouse "loses" the draggable

Here the issue is described in more details:
http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/AdvancedMouseEventModelForSVG-1/index.html#S3.2
Also here the author tried to fix UX by leveraging mouseout event:
http://nuclearprojects.com/blog/svg-click-and-drag-object-with-mouse-code/

I copied the above code snippet here: http://codepen.io/cmer41k/pen/zNGwpa

**The question I have is:**

Is there no other way (provided by pure SVG) to prevent such "loss" of SVG element while mouse moves too fast?

My attempt to solve this was:
- detect (somehow) that mouseout event happened without finishing the dragging.
- and if so (we sort of detected "disconnect") - reconnect the SVG element with current mouse position.

**Is there a reason why this wouldn't work?**

Code:

```js
    var click=false; // flag to indicate when shape has been clicked
    var clickX, clickY; // stores cursor location upon first click
    var moveX=0, moveY=0; // keeps track of overall transformation
    var lastMoveX=0, lastMoveY=0; // stores previous transformation (move)
    function mouseDown(evt){
        evt.preventDefault(); // Needed for Firefox to allow dragging correctly
        click=true;
        clickX = evt.clientX; 
        clickY = evt.clientY;
        evt.target.setAttribute("fill","green");
    }

    function move(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        if(click){
            moveX = lastMoveX + ( evt.clientX – clickX );
            moveY = lastMoveY + ( evt.clientY – clickY );

            evt.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + moveX + "," + moveY + ")");
        }
    }

    function endMove(evt){
        click=false;
        lastMoveX = moveX;
        lastMoveY = moveY;
        evt.target.setAttribute("fill","gray");
    }
```

Comment: `evt.clientY – clickY` these are no legal javascript minuses...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important part of your code is missing, namely how or more specifically on which element you register the events.

What you basically do to **prevent this problem is to register the mousemove and mouseup events on the outermost svg element, and not on the element you want to drag**.

```
svg.addEventListener("mousemove", move)
svg.addEventListener("mouseup", endMove)
```

When starting the drag, register the events on the svg element, and when done unregister them.

```
svg.removeEventListener("mousemove", move)
svg.removeListener("mouseup", endMove)
```

you have to store the element you are currently dragging, so it is available in the other event handlers.

what i additionally do is to set pointer-events to "none" on the dragged
element so that you can react to mouse events underneath the dragged element (f.e. finding the drop target...)

```
evt.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none")
```

but don't forget to set it back to something sensible when dragging is done

```
evt.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "all")
```

```js
var click = false; // flag to indicate when shape has been clicked
var clickX, clickY; // stores cursor location upon first click
var moveX = 0,
  moveY = 0; // keeps track of overall transformation
var lastMoveX = 0,
  lastMoveY = 0; // stores previous transformation (move)
var currentTarget = null

function mouseDown(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); // Needed for Firefox to allow dragging correctly
  click = true;
  clickX = evt.clientX;
  clickY = evt.clientY;
  evt.target.setAttribute("fill", "green");
  // register move events on outermost SVG Element
  currentTarget = evt.target
  svg.addEventListener("mousemove", move)
  svg.addEventListener("mouseup", endMove)
  evt.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none")
}

function move(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (click) {
    moveX = lastMoveX + (evt.clientX - clickX);
    moveY = lastMoveY + (evt.clientY - clickY);
    currentTarget.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + moveX + "," + moveY + ")");
  }
}

function endMove(evt) {
  click = false;
  lastMoveX = moveX;
  lastMoveY = moveY;
  currentTarget.setAttribute("fill", "gray");
  svg.removeEventListener("mousemove", move)
  svg.removeEventListener("mouseup", endMove)
  currentTarget.setAttribute("pointer-events", "all")
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black; background: #E0FFFF;">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="600" fill="none" pointer-events="all" />
  <circle id="mycirc" cx="60" cy="60" r="22" onmousedown="mouseDown(evt)" />
</svg>
```

**more advanced**

there are still two things not so well with this code.

1. it does not work for viewBoxed SVGs nor for elements inside
   transformed parents.
2. all the globals are bad coding practice.

here is how to fix those:
Nr. 1 is solved by converting mouse coordinates into local coordinates using the inverse of getScreenCTM (CTM = Current Transformation Matrix).

```
function globalToLocalCoords(x, y) {
    var p = elem.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
    var m = elem.parentNode.getScreenCTM()
    p.x = x
    p.y = y
    return p.matrixTransform(m.inverse())
  }
```

For nr. 2 see this implementation:

```js
var dre = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable")
for (var i = 0; i < dre.length; i++) {
  var o = new Draggable(dre[i])
}

function Draggable(elem) {
  this.target = elem
  this.clickPoint = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.lastMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.currentMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.target.addEventListener("mousedown", this)
  this.handleEvent = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    this.clickPoint = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
    this.target.classList.add("dragged")
    this.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none")
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
  }
  this.move = function(evt) {
    var p = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
    this.currentMove.x = this.lastMove.x + (p.x - this.clickPoint.x)
    this.currentMove.y = this.lastMove.y + (p.y - this.clickPoint.y)
    this.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + this.currentMove.x + "," + this.currentMove.y + ")")
  }.bind(this)

  this.endMove = function(evt) {
    this.lastMove.x = this.currentMove.x
    this.lastMove.y = this.currentMove.y
    this.target.classList.remove("dragged")
    this.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "all")
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
  }.bind(this)

  function globalToLocalCoords(x, y) {
    var p = elem.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
    var m = elem.parentNode.getScreenCTM()
    p.x = x
    p.y = y
    return p.matrixTransform(m.inverse())
  }
}
```

```css
.dragged {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 1 1;
}
.draggable{cursor:move}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 800 600" style="border: 1px solid black; background: #E0FFFF;">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="600" fill="none" pointer-events="all" />
  <circle class="draggable" id="mycirc" cx="60" cy="60" r="22" fill="blue" />
  <g transform="rotate(45,175,75)">
    <rect class="draggable" id="mycirc" x="160" y="60" width="30" height="30" fill="green" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(200 200) scale(2 2)">
    <g class="draggable">
      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="yellow"/>
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="0" fill="red">I'm draggable</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Can you help me understand (expand your answer a bit) on why its important to "dynamically" assign and remove the listeners? will this solve the sticky, fast mouse move "disconnect" problems?

Comment: as the event handler are on the svg element, you would get move events fired all the time. in a static handler you could just place an if statement around the drag code, but its generally more elegant to not use if if not needed. it's more resouce friendly this way, and it seperates the code from the presentation. You can use this code on any SVG without touch the svg code itself...  What solves the "sticky" "disconnect" problem is that the handler is registerd on the outermost svg element, and not the element you drag around. I have highlighted these parts in the answer...

Comment: BTW your code snippet does work really well. So I guess that dynamic listeners thing + other items do make it possible to get very decent mouse behavior with SVG!

Comment: AWESOME, thank you for your answer - very helpful for my project!

Comment: Holger, sorry to bother, but a small nuance that I can't resolve based on your code - I was trying to add also another listener into the Draaggable object - dblclick - and yet I fail to do it. Is there a reason why double click is not supported this way?

Comment: where are you trying to add the eventlistener and what should happen on dblclick? I've created a [fidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duLf9xqt/), just make your changes there and i'll have a look at the code

Comment: I was basically trying to add another listener to the Draggable obj - dblclick, so that if you double click any such created shapes user sort of could "select" it. I think I succeeded with this here: http://codepen.io/cmer41k/pen/MJapLK but alas I couldn't leverage the line with pointer-lock;( as the moment I set it, ny dbl click is gone;(

Comment: You will also see that in the code you helped me with I tried to embed a few useful functions (like parsing certain paths etc). I am yet to understand/learn - now that I have the javascript objects - how can I "link" them to the HTML. So that I could for instance access pathPoints property etc...you helped a lot already - sorry if this is too much;)

Comment: you did add the dblclick feature in exactly the right way! In your case you wont need `pointer-events` so just do leave it commented out.

selectedShape (or this.target) holds a reference to the path object. you can access the data with regular DOM function like `this.target.getAttribute("d")` ...   or use the [SVG DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html)

Comment: I have onmouseenter and onmouseleave for my test rectangle, whey change stroke-dasharray, when I use "pointer-events" as you suggested my dasharray return to original state while dragging.