# Drag group of svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg, draggable

I'm trying to drag a circle with a number inside it that's an svg overlay over an image.

Using this example (http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/draggable-svg-element) it works fine for just the circle. But I need both the circle and the text (number) inside the circle to move when I drag it, so I want the group to move at the same time.

```
        <div>
        <p>Image inside svg:</p>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800" height="400">
                <image  x="0" y="0" width="800" height="400" xlink:href="myimage.png"/>
            <a xlink:href="/svg/index.html" target="_top">
                <g>
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20" fill="red"
                    class="draggable"
                    transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"
                    onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"></circle>
                <text x="100" y="100" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em" style="font-size: 1.5em;">1</text>
                </g>
            </a>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
    var selectedElement = 0;
var currentX = 0;
var currentY = 0;
var currentMatrix = 0;

function selectElement(evt) {
    selectedElement = evt.target;
    currentX = evt.clientX;
    currentY = evt.clientY;
    currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7, -1).split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < currentMatrix.length; i++) {
        currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
    }

    selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
    selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deselectElement(evt)");
    selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(evt)");
}

function moveElement(evt) {
    dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
    dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
    currentMatrix[4] += dx;
    currentMatrix[5] += dy;
    newMatrix = "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")";

    selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", newMatrix);
    currentX = evt.clientX;
    currentY = evt.clientY;
}

function deselectElement(evt) {
    if (selectedElement != 0) {
        selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
        selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout");
        selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
        selectedElement = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm not very familiar with manipulating svg at all, but it's almost doing all I need, and any ideas how I would make the whole group move simultaneously would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Attach the event listener to the `<g>` element. Your solution might work for you, but not in more general cases. Most people tend to use the [tag:d3.js] library for these use cases; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023269#43029046) for what your question then shrinks to.

Comment: Just moving the event listener didn't work for me. But the d3.js library worked perfectly, so thanks for that. I'm perfectly happy with that answer, so if you want credit, please post it as a reply and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Comment: please also see my detailed answer on dragging Elements here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514967/yes-no-is-there-a-way-to-improve-mouse-dragging-with-pure-svg-tools/41518545#41518545